# Explain SQL "SELECT count(*) FROM t AS 2 WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1"

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone, please, explain syntax of following request? The question is - if test2 is a result of count function, it is just a number. How can it be treated as a table (revenue.country_code = test2.country_code)? This code works, but I don't understand how. Thanks a lot for any answer.

```
SELECT customer_user_id, revenue, country_code FROM revenue 
WHERE
(SELECT count(*) 
FROM revenue AS test2 
WHERE revenue.country_code = test2.country_code 
AND test2.revenue > revenue.revenue) < 5 
and media_source = 'facebook'
ORDER BY country_code, revenue DESC;
```

Comment: This is known as a [correlated subquery](https://learnsql.com/blog/correlated-sql-subquery-5-minutes/)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html

Comment: Test2 is not the result of a count function, is the table over the one you make the count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html). The Subquery contains a reference to the table in the main query in its WHERE clause and it works similar to a join.

What this is saying in english is "We compare the number of records in this table for this country_id that have a higher revenue than this record's revenue. If that count is less than 5, then keep this record".

If it helps to understand, this could also be written with window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   (
       SELECT customer_user_id, revenue, country_code 
           ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country_code ORDER BY revenue DESC) as revenuerank
       FROM revenue
       WHERE media_source = 'facebook'
   ) sub
WHERE sub.revenuerank < 5
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell, how can function from your example look if I want sum(revenue)?

Comment: You'll have to explain better. How would sum(revenue) fit into this logic that limits which rows are in your result set? Recognize here that `count(*)` in the correlated subquery isn't really being used for any aggregating output, rather just to determine if the record in question is in the top 5 by revenue. It's an interim step/shortcut for doing `top 5 by distinct customer_id`.

Comment: The problem is "select top 5 profitable users for each country", that's why I ask about sum(revenue).

Comment: If you use that same window function query that I shared hee you could change `FROM revenue` to `FROM (SELECT customer_user_id, sum(revenue) as revenue, country_code FROM revenue GROUP BY customer_user_id, country_code) revenue` and let 'er rip.

Comment: Thank you. As I see, problem solved. I figured out this query:
    select *
from
 (select customer_user_id,
 country_code,
 sum(revenue),
    row_number() over (partition by country_code order by sum(revenue) desc) topN
from revenue 
WHERE media_source = 'facebook'
group by customer_user_id,
 country_code
    order by country_code,topN asc) sub
where sub.topN <= 5;